# Изменение поведение базового класса в зависимости от свойств потомка

Tags: ооп

Задача:

Есть базовый класс, который реализует какую-то общую функциональность, используемую большинством потомков.

Но. Есть некоторые потомки, для которых эта общая функциональность должна быть отключена.

Я вижу три варианта решения данной задачи:

1. Внутренняя protected переменная в базовом классе, в зависимости от
   которой будет или не будет выполняться нужная функциональность.
   Значение этой переменной устанавливает базовый класс по умолчанию, а
   потомки могут изменить.
2. Виртуальный метод базового класса, в зависимости от возвращаемого
   значения которого будет или не будет выполняться нужная
   функциональность. Значение по умолчанию возвращает метод базового
   класса. Потомок может перекрыть данный метод и вернуть нужное ему
   значение.
3. Общая функциональность выносится в один виртуальный protected не sealed метод. Потомок, при необходимости может перекрыть данный метод, полностью убрав или изменив нужное поведение.

Какое из решений лучше?

Может быть есть другие варианты решения?

Comment: Чище было бы ввести в иерархию еще один класс, в котором этой функциональности нет.

Comment: Igor, Изменение иерархии подразумевает ветвление наследования. В данной задаче изменение иерархии не рассматривается, так как наследование должно быть от одного базового класса без ветвления.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант, переопределяешь у потомка метод базового класса, функциональность которого хочешь убрать, и делаешь его пустым. Часто вижу такое решение.

Comment: это кстати относится к понятию полиморфизм

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил третье решение в описание вопроса.